# Symfony backend to Wordpress frontend

Tags: wordpress, symfony

is there a way to send Symfony’s data from its action to Wordpress page? 
For example Symfony’s action returns an array and in a Wordpress page I could iterate it?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress use template that are basic php file.

So you can make request to any rest api you want you using php. You can use your symfony rest api if you want.

Simply go in wordpress create pages and create template that will make your request to Symfony and display what you need.

It's really not recommanded but for a special case it could be possible.

You maybe should take the time to simply move your data in the wordpress DB.

Comment: The response from Symfony has to be a custom post type otherwise Wordpress won’t be dynamic, right?

Comment: In my solution wordpress would only manage the navigation of your website the content comming from Symfony would be normal SQL query or REST query. I don't think you will be able to use the wordpress querys